# bettercap - arp spoofing

Tags: arp-spoofing, bettercap

I am new with bettercap, I am trying to do a simple ARP Spoof attack.
Reading the online doc, I tried with:

1) `bettercap # launch bettercap` '

2) `set arp.spoof.targets "MYVICTIM IP" #example : 192.168.1.6`

3) `arp.spoof on`

but this doesn't work, I can't see any of my victim's packets.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing 2 key things here:

1. You need to enable full duplex arp spoofing (so the target thinks you're the router, the router thinks you're the target). Enter `set arp.spoof.fullduplex true` in bettercap for this.
2. You need to tell bettercap to sniff for traffic (assuming you're not using another tool). You can do this with `net.sniff on`, again in bettercap.

If that cuts off the internet for the target, make sure you've enabled IP forwarding (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14056/what-is-kernel-ip-forwarding).